# ensure that arrow keys skip separator items in a WPF menu?

Tags: wpf, separator

In my WPF menu I have a separator (`System.Windows.Controls.Separator`) item that seems to invisibly accept focus when navigating the menu via the arrow keys.  I'd like the arrow navigation path to skip these separators.  I've tried setting `IsEnabled` and `IsTabStop` are set to `false`, but neither of these seem to have any effect.

In XAML, how can I specify that separator items should be skipped?

UPDATE: Here's the currently style XAML for my separator:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" 
                            Margin="10,5,10,5">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>

                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1" >
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource Nui10Color}" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource Nui50Color}" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>

                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  I needed to set Focusable on the MenuItem itself, not the template:

```
<!-- style for menu item separators -->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}" 
           x:Key="MenuItemStyleSeparator">
                            <!-- the following line is what I needed -->
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Separator IsEnabled="false" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on them. It should disable them from all hit-testing